# Check if variable is a text file

Tags: batch-file

How would I go about checking if a variable is a .txt file?

My code isn't working:

```
if /I "%ph2file%" NEQ "*.txt" echo This file is not a .txt file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "quick and dirty" way (check last four characters):

```
if /i "%ph2file:~-4%" neq ".txt" echo no .txt file
```

the "clean" way (check the extension):

```
for %a in ("%ph2file%") do echo if "%~xa" neq ".txt" echo no .txt file
```